# Can't reference FSharp.Core in C# project on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, f#, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I have the following on that machine:
(copied from "about" window, removed irrelevant parts)

```
Xamarin Studio  
Version 4.0.12 (build 3)  
Runtime:  
    Mono 3.2.1 ((no/f3f789e)  
    GTK 2.24.20  
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)  
    Package version: 302010001  


Build Information  
Release ID: 400120003  
Git revision: 593d7acb1cb78ceeeb482d5133cf1fe514467e39  
Build date: 2013-08-07 20:30:53+0000  
Xamarin addins: 25a0858b281923e666b09259ad4746b774e0a873  

Operating System  
Mac OS X 10.8.4  
Darwin mac03 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0  
    Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013  
    root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

And I have the F# addin installed. I can even build F# projects, but when I try to use some classes from F# library in C# project, I get error (can't find FSharp.Core package). Strangely enough, the FSharp.Core reference is also highlighted with red in F# project too, but that doesn't prevent it from building successfully.
The picture below is screenshot with the error displayed.
Have you any ideas how to deal with it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Could it be related to this issue?

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/30

Comment: Most likely yes.
BTW, there were updates to various parts of Xamarin tools since I asked the question, but I had no time to check out if this bug was fixed. I will look later. Thanks and +1 for pointing this issue.